# Parse JSON value as Enum in Rust

Tags: rust

I have enum that wraps primitives:

```
#[deriving(Decodable)]
enum MyValue {
  MyString(String),
  MyF64(f64),
  MyF32(f32),
  MyI64(i64),
  MyI32(i32),
  ...
  ...
}
```

Now I want to convert a JSON string into corresponding variant of `MyValue`, for instance:

```
let v: MyValue = parse_json("3.14") // MyF32(3.14f32)
let v: MyValue = parse_json("3.14151515151515") // MyF64(3.14151515151515f64)
let v: MyValue = parse_json("42") // MyI32(42)
let v: MyValue = parse_json("\"hello\"") // MyString("hello")
```

If I do it directly:

```
let my_value: MyValue = json::decode("3.14").unwrap();
```

I get:

`task '<main>' failed at 'called`Result::unwrap()`on an`Err`value: ExpectedError(String or Object, 3.14)'`

Is it possible to do above with only Rust type system?

If not, what is the approach that should be taken? Should I use regexes/PEG parser or something else?

**[playpen](http://is.gd/z6RFsM)**

Comment: The `Decodable` instance created by `#[deriving]` is designed to decode the output of a `#[deriving]` `Encodable` instance; enums in particular work a bit strangely (they have to store which variant they are, and so aren't just the raw value of their contents). You have some relatively complicated rules for choosing which variant comes out of a value, so you will have to parse manually.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you'll be able to do this with `#[deriving(Decodable)]`. Here is a fragment produced by `rustc --pretty expanded`:

```
__arg_0.read_enum("MyValue", |_d|
    _d.read_enum_variant(["MyString", "MyF64", "MyF32", "MyI64", "MyI32"], |_d, i|
        ::std::result::Ok(match i {
            0u => MyString(match _d.read_enum_variant_arg(0u, |_d| ::serialize::Decodable::decode(_d)) {
                Ok(__try_var) => __try_var,
                Err(__try_var) => return Err(__try_var),
            }),
            1u => MyF64(match _d.read_enum_variant_arg(0u, |_d| ::serialize::Decodable::decode(_d)) {
                Ok(__try_var) => __try_var,
                Err(__try_var) => return Err(__try_var),
            }),
            2u => ...
```

That is, it dispatches on enum variant index provided by the decoder. In fact, compatible JSON would look like this, you can [see it yourself](http://is.gd/n4ihB7):

```
{ "variant": 1, "fields": [12345] }  // corresponds to MyF64(12345)
```

In general I see no way to do what you want in *any* language, not only in Rust. JSON is just not sophisticated enough to distinguish between different kinds of integers, for example. Also Rust `Decodable` trait requires you to determine exact variant of the enum you're decoding using some kind of metadata; you can't read arbitrary value there and decide on its type at runtime. So you need to write some kind of parser yourself, however, I strongly recommend reconsider what you are doing. JSON is likely not the language you need here.

Comment: I have no control over incoming JSON. I wanted to make a type-safe wrapper around JSON values and tried to use enum for it

Comment: Unfortunately, JSON is not *that* type-safe - its set of types is fairly limited. For example, there is only three primitive types - numbers (at least 64-bit floating-point), strings and booleans. So you just can't differentiate between, say, `f32` and `f64` in JSON without some kind of discriminator. Moreover, there is an appropriate type in the `serialize` crate already - it's called [`Json`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/type.Json.html), naturally. You can parse a string into it using [`json::from_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/json/fn.from_str.html).

Comment: @ValentinVasilyev I don't remember how `rustc-serialize` works and if it's any different from `Serde`, but `Serde` works as follows (IIRC): negative integer -> `i64`, positive integer -> `u64`, float -> `f64`. You can simply downcast from there if you think the type choosen by `Serde` is too big.