# Conditionally decoding JSON based on a field in the JSON

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am receiving JSON from an API and the response can be one of 30 types. Each type has a unique set of fields, but all responses have a field `type` which states which type it is.

My approach is to use [serde](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde_json/serde_json/). I create a struct for each response type and make them decodable. Once I have that how do I choose which struct should be used for a freshly received message?

At the moment, I've created another struct `TypeStruct` with only a single field for `type`. I decode the JSON into a `TypeStruct`, then choose the appropriate struct for received message, based on type value, and decode the message again.

I would like to get rid of this decoding duplication.

Comment: Your current solution is what I would do. What do you think would be better or more efficient about avoiding the "decoding duplication"?

Comment: I'm comming from python, so I don't feel comfortable with stacilly typed languages. But if you say, that my approach is ok, I'll stick with it.

Comment: Just my opinion, but this sounds like a good example of premature worrying about optimization. Get your code to run and see if you deem it fast enough. If not, profile your code before changing it – perhaps the JSON decoding isn't even the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the existing enum deserialization. I'll give a step by step example to deserialize your format to the following enum:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize)]
enum MyType {
    A {gar: ()},
    B {test: i32},
    C {blub: String},
}
```

1. Start with an example json string:

   ```
   let json = r#"{"type": "B", "test": 42}"#;
   ```
2. Turn it into a [`Value`](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde_json/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) enum

   ```
   let mut json: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
   ```
3. Rip out the `type` field

   ```
   let type_ = {
       let obj = json.as_object_mut().expect("object");
       let type_ = obj.remove("type").expect("`type` field");
       if let serde_json::Value::String(s) = type_ {
           s
       } else {
           panic!("type field not a string");
       }
   };
   ```
4. Create the "proper" enum json. A struct with a single field where the name of the field is the enum variant and the value of the field is the variant value

   ```
   let mut enum_obj = std::collections::BTreeMap::new();
   enum_obj.insert(type_, json);
   let json = serde_json::Value::Object(enum_obj);
   ```
5. Use the generated json deserializer to turn the json into a value of your enum

   ```
   let obj: MyType = serde_json::from_value(json).unwrap();
   ```

Comment: Any numbers or gut feelings on the efficiency of this compared to the "decode it twice" solution outlined in the question?

Comment: it's more of a DRY solution. This way you don't need to handle any type in two locations. You just need to declare the enum. Never to match over all the possible types or anything. Speedwise this is probably worse than the solution offered in the Question (except if there are a lot of `String` fields and no struct/enum fields, then it's probably faster than the solution in the Question). It's hard to know without seeing the exact code. General solutions that are faster require precise knowledge about the field order in the json string and/or hacks on serde

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that, something like you suggested is possible. Can I use the same technique with rust-serialize?

Comment: I'm sure that works, too, yes. It also has a `Json` enum for raw json and it has a special format for enums (most likely the same as serde?). So the conversion of my above code to `rustc-serialize` should be straight forward

Comment: unfortuenatly, rustc-serialize can't do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604339/parse-json-value-as-enum-in-rust


so this example (http://is.gd/XB1TiG) produces 

{"variant":"Message","fields":["123","superuser","some text","beginning of epoch"]}